# iOS navigation controller required when adding launch screen to app?

Tags: ios, storyboard, launch-screen

My app works fine with Main.storyboard and now I want to add LaunchScreen.storyboard.  Simple question: Is a navigation controller required to do this?  I'll go research based on the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no need to add `UINavigationController` for add LaunchScreen.storyboard. UINavigationController is for only navigate to one UIViewController to another UIViewController.